# A misprint in `The Giver`? ("it lay in the future")

Tags: tense, lie-lay-lain-laid

> Lily looked up, her eyes wide. “The Ceremony of Twelve,” she whispered in an awed voice. Even the smallest children—Lily’s age and younger—knew that it **lay** in the future for each of them.

It is a passage form *The Giver* (Lois Lowry). Looks to me as the verb **lay** is an incorrect form. If it is Present Tense—it should be *it lays*. If it is Past Tense—it should be *it laid*.

Comment: *Lay* is transitive, but the verb here has no direct object; it has to be *lie*.

Comment: It should be *lies*, in standard English. The answer does a disservice by not correcting this and by using the same non-standard usage you ask about in the sentence *Lowry's usage lays [sic] somewhere between definitions 4,5 and 7*. It should be *lies* not *lays*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Lay*** is also a valid past tense of the the verb **lie**.

Lowry's usage lays somewhere between [definitions 4,5 and 7](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lie?show=0&t=1373209184):

> 4 : to have direction : extend 
>   5
>     a : to occupy a certain relative place or position 
>     b : to have a place in relation to something else 
>     c : to have an effect through mere presence, weight, or relative position 
>   7
>   a : to have place : exist

Besides the literal interpretation of the event having a position in the children's future, 5c also can be applied because the knowledge of the Ceremony in their futures weighs on their minds even now.

Comment: I think it's meaning 5c: **to have an effect through mere presence, weight, or relative position** : *remorse lay heavily on him*. In this case, I think the effect is the awe that is mentioned in the passage.

Comment: @J.R.- Ok, you talked me into it.  She probably does intend that the knowledge does have an effect on the children.

Comment: Jim, I agree that it's not exactly easy to match up a particular usage of the word _lie_ with a particular definition listed in the dictionary. It's a very versatile word, and, despite it's simplicity, it's a bit tricky to define in plain words.

Comment: @J.R. I disagree. The "to have an effect" would be a use with "on"; the use with "in the future" + implies 5a, and the "for them" is the relative; *their* future.

Comment: @Stoney: Well, then, at least we agree on the part about it being tricky... :^)

Comment: -1 for using the same non-standard use of *lay* that this question asks about in your sentence *Lowry's usage **lays** [sic] somewhere between definitions 4,5 and 7:*. The link goes to *lie*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - I think that might have been on purpose... :-)